# How to cache a spring MVC application with html 5?

Tags: html, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I'ld like to build a cache for my spring MVC application using HTML5 Standard.

My project architecture is as below :

In my web.xml I added this :

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>manifest</extension>
  <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I created a .manifest file located in WEB-INF folder which contains

```
CACHE MANIFEST
 # version 1

CACHE:
home.jsp
css/style.lesss
```

home.jsp file header is :

```
<html manifest="collabook.manifest">
```

no file is cached (safari web inspector)

How to achieve my goal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, add this to your dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<resources mapping="/files/to/cache/**" location="/files/to/cache/"
```

and add this to your view resolver:

```
<bean id="myview"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/files/to/cache/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.manifest</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You also need a MVC Controller to pick up the URI if you want to do something custom for dynamic content.

Comment: when  i add the bean my jsp pages are not  displayed nor cached

Comment: were they showing before you added this? I think the prefix needs to be "collabook" based on what you have above.